# Using Microphone with javascript

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

I'm creating a web-app which needs an audio recording from the user's computer, How do I accomplish this using JavaScript? I've heard about the getusermedia utilities but that's not very stable and I'm looking for a better alternative. Can someone suggest me anything?

Answer (score 0):

scriptcam offers a flash alternative instead of using `getusermedia`. It is very stable for now.https://www.scriptcam.com/

`getusermedia` is quite stable and simple. check out this jsfiddle i made much earlier:http://jsfiddle.net/XHzT6/(warning:might only work on chrome.)  Hopefully, you might change your mind.

cheers!